# Hibernate/JPA creates an invalid sql query by arranging joins for OneToOne in wrong order

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Here is the JPA query in question

```java
    @Query("select distinct t from Task t " +
            "join TaskEventLog tel on tel.task.id = t.id " +
    
            // the join in the next line is what generates the invalid sql
            "join Vineyard v on t.taskLocation.vineyard.id = v.id "
    
            "where v.id in :vineyardIds " +
            "and tel.timestamp >= :startDate " +
            "and tel.timestamp <= :endDate " +
            "and t.status <> app.vinitor.server.task.evenStatus.EventStatus.DRAFT " +
            "and tel.deleted=0 " +
            "and t.deleted=0 " +
            "order by t.plannedStartDate, t.priority")
    List<Task> getByVineyardsAndEventLogTimeframe(List<UUID> vineyardIds, @Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```

and here is the output produced using `hibernate.show-sql`

```sql
select distinct t1_0.id,
                t1_0.additional_info,
                t1_0.created_afterwards,
                t1_0.deleted,
                t1_0.next_task_id,
                t1_0.planned_completion_date,
                t1_0.planned_start_date,
                t1_0.priority,
                t1_0.rank,
                t1_0.report_id,
                t1_0.status,
                t1_0.task_location_id,
                t1_0.task_type_id
from vin_task t1_0
         join vin_task_event_log t2_0 on t2_0.task_id = t1_0.id

         // here we join using a table name that is not yet defined !?
         join vin_vineyard v1_0 on t4_0.vineyard_id = v1_0.id
         // this line should be swapped with the previous line to form a valid query
         join vin_task_location t4_0 on t4_0.id = t1_0.task_location_id

where v1_0.id in (?, ?, ?, ?)
  and t2_0.timestamp >= ?
  and t2_0.timestamp <= ?
  and t1_0.status != 'DRAFT'
  and t2_0.deleted = 0
  and t1_0.deleted = 0
order by t1_0.planned_start_date, t1_0.priority
```

And the exception that is thrown when this query is executed

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=33) Unknown column 't4_0.vineyard_id' in 'on clause'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:282) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:370) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
```

Some more info about the entities in question for clarity

```java
@Entity
public class Task {
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private TaskLocation taskLocation;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class TaskLocation extends Location {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "taskLocation")
    private Task task;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Location {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vineyard_id")
    private Vineyard vineyard;
    ...
}
```

The code above seemed to work when were still using Spring 2.0, but we upgraded to 3.0 and the errors seems to only occur since then, so I'm not quite sure if something with the internally used hibernate/jpa version is responsible for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I was actually able to reconstruct the problem from your posted code, even though it left out some of the main entities in your query!

For the record, the reproducer is:

```java
@SessionFactory
@DomainModel(annotatedClasses = {BuggTest.Task.class, BuggTest.Location.class, BuggTest.TaskLocation.class,BuggTest.Vineyard.class, BuggTest.TaskEventLog.class})
public class BuggTest {

    @Test void test(SessionFactoryScope scope) {
        scope.inTransaction( s-> {
            s.createQuery(
                    "select distinct t from Task t join TaskEventLog tel on tel.task.id = t.id join Vineyard v on t.taskLocation.vineyard.id = v.id",
                    Task.class).getResultList();
        });
    }

    @Entity(name = "Task")
    @Table(name = "vin_task")
    public class Task {
        @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "task_location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private TaskLocation taskLocation;

    }

    @Entity(name = "TaskLocation")
    @Table(name = "vin_task_location")
    public class TaskLocation extends Location {
        @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "taskLocation")
        private Task task;

    }

    @Entity(name = "Location")
    @Table(name = "vin_location")
    public class Location {
        @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "vineyard_id")
        private Vineyard vineyard;
    }

    @Entity(name = "Vineyard")
    @Table(name = "vin_vineyard")
    public class Vineyard {
        @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    }

    @Entity(name = "TaskEventLog")
    @Table(name = "vin_task_event_log")
    public class TaskEventLog {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
        Long id;

        @ManyToOne Task task;
    }

}
```

I have opened https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16522.

(In future please try to simplify and clean up your code before posting on stackoverflow. Thanks.)

Comment: Thank you very much for doing that! Sorry, yeah i wasn't sure how much info i should add for context, guess I could have done a better job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug and Gavin was so nice as to create a ticket for it.

In the meantime, I found a little workaround for the issue, after going through the hibernate 6.0 migration guide, I saw that there is an alternative  way for joining mapped fields in an entity using JPQL.

JPQL query with `JOIN` that produces invalid SQL

```java
@Query("select t from Task t " +
            "join Vineyard v on t.taskLocation.vineyard.id = v.id " +
            "where v.id in :vineyardIds")
```

Instead we can directly join on the field of the entity like this

```java
@Query("select t from Task t " +
            "join t.taskLocation.vineyard v " +
            "where v.id in :vineyardIds")
```

I am not quite sure why the first query does not produce valid SQL and the second does, but in my case it works as a workaround.